# Getting a blank screen when deploying react app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjvM.jpg)Once the app is built, I am only getting a blank screen on Heroku.

My root package.json has the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {       
"start": "node index.js",
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run           build"
},
```

I defined the engines with my versions of node and npm.

I also added
"homepage": "." in my package.json

In my server index.js I have the following:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
}

app.get("*", (req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ "client/build", "index.html"))
})
```

Finally, here is the heroku logs --tail:

```
2022-03-30T21:52:08.924292+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from up to starting
2022-03-30T21:52:09.000000+00:00 app\[api\]: Build succeeded
2022-03-30T21:52:09.821908+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-03-30T21:52:09.867067+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Going down, terminating child processes...
2022-03-30T21:52:10.008660+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 0
2022-03-30T21:52:16.272272+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2022-03-30T21:52:17.144106+00:00 app\[web.1\]: ls: cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory*
2022-03-30T21:52:17.144325+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-
```

Comment: If you run a one-off dyno from inside your project's directory (`heroku run bash`), can you verify that the `/app/build` directory exists? (e.g., `ls -l /app/build`)?

Comment: Looking at this again there seems to be a discrepancy between your file structure (`./client/build`) and the Heroku log (`./build`). Heroku seems to be looking for your React static build in `/app/build` (`$PWD` is `/app` on the dyno) instead of `/app/client/build`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!When running heroku run bash I get the same error - ls: cannot access '/app/build/static/js/*.js': No such file or directory
Error injecting runtime env: bundle not found '/app/build/static/js/*.js'. See: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-bundle-location

Comment: Also this is my static.json:

    {
        "root": "client/build/",
        "clean_urls": false,
        "routes": {
          "/**": "index.html"
        }
      }

Comment: According to the logs, Heroku is looking for `/app/build/**` (not `/app/client/build/**`). In your `static.json` file, what happens if you change `"root": "client/build/"` to `"root": "build/"`? Also, if you were to run `ls -l /app` on the dyno, is there a `client` or `build` directory present?

Comment: I get 404 Not Found nginx if I change root to just "build/"